# How to write a Thesis with font of size 14pt?

Tags: thesis

I want to write my thesis in latex, with a font of size 14pt. I wrote

```
\documentclass[14pt,oneside,a4papper]{book}
```

but the font is not of 14pt. Can someone tell me how can I write with 14pt?
Thank you!

Comment: `memoir` suport 14 pt fonts. Beside this it also has many other features which can be handy ...

Comment: @Huang_d if I try to use extsize package, it tells me that "MiKTeX encountered an internal error."

Comment: @g.pomegranate Great! I then suggest you to ask a new question about this specific issue. Please remember to add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `book` class supports only `10`, `11`, and `12`pt sizes. You need the `extbook` to be able to use `14pt`. Better options exist, like `scrbook` or the `memoir` class, both support `14pt` size out of the box.

```
\documentclass[14pt,oneside,a4paper]{extbook}
\usepackage{geometry}

\begin{document}

some text here ..

\end{document}
```

Comment: If a I put extbook, it tells me: "MiKTeX encountered an internal error."

Comment: Package `extsizes.sty`?